# What's the proper way to handle incorporating changes from another's commit or pull request into your local code?

Tags: git, github

Sorry if the title isn't too clear, I'm not exactly sure how to word this myself, but I'll try to explain in more detail here.

Back in October I started working on a new project - a music bot for Discord written in Python, because I didn't like the existing self-hosting options I could find at the time. I decided to make a repository for it on GitHub, both for others to use and so I could use `git pull` to update the files more easily on the VPS I'm using to host my instance of it.

No one has made any forks or pull requests of it yet, but lately I'd got to thinking about it and realized I'm not entirely sure what the process for integrating someone else's code into mine would be?

As in, if someone starts working on a bug fix or a feature of their own, makes a PR, and I want to accept it and merge with mine - but I'm also separately in the middle of doing some work in my local files, is there any sort of proper procedure there for combining their changes with mine besides just manually looking over it and deciding how to integrate it?

Comment: Do you use multiple branches, like main, feature1 etc.?

Comment: Thus far I've just been committing and pushing to the master branch, though after some recent searching I'm now aware isn't very recommended.

Comment: If your work has merge conflicts with someone else's, then you must manually examine the changes to resolve the conflicts, there's no other way.

Comment: @TylerLiu That's what I had assumed, I'll just do that then. I'm not extremely familiar with git so I wasn't sure if there was a standard practice here I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although git does allow you to set remote repos to feature branches, you generally will only ever pull / PR into integration branches of some kind.

A common pattern would be to have a `master` and a `develop` branch. the Master branch is a source of truth, and PR's are merged from `develop` to `master`.

`develop` is an integration branch. It is branched from `master`, and changes are PR'd into `develop`, then eventually PR'd into `master`.

Developers should cut branches from `develop`, make changes, then PR into `develop` for review.

When you and a colleague are working on changes in the same project, it is important to PR and integrate **often** so others can integrate the work into their own branches.

It is common practice to constantly be performing git pulls on develop or taking in the latest changes that developers may have made.

So to answer your question, you both integrate into a common branch and pull those changes into your own feature branches as you go. Make changes often so it's easier to merge.

See [gitflow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for a commonly adopted branching strategy.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, what I would do is start using a separate branch and commit+push to it much more frequently as I'm doing work, and then pull that work into the master branch once I'm ready to call it stable/finished?
Right now I've only been committing when I've fully completed whatever tasks I'd set out for a particular version - which is typically a week or more between those commits. Instead, I should try making a new branch to constantly push updates to without it going into the master/"stable" branch?

Comment: The rate at which you PR and which strategy is up to you since it's your repo. When working on teams, you should consider merging in changes more frequently so your teammates can perform code reviews as you go, rather than all at once at the end (although we still see waterfall merges even in the professional space all the time). But yes, you can merge into an integration branch, then cut a release when stable, or straight into master which is also a viable strategy for [trunk based development](https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/continuous-integration/trunk-based-development).

Answer (score 1):

The problem also applies to simpler cases, e.g. when you make changes on two different computers.

> is there any sort of proper procedure there for combining their changes with mine besides just manually looking over it and deciding how to integrate it?

1. In majority of merges there are no conflicts do deal with because changes are in different files and even if the changes affect the same files git may be able to resolve them automatically.
2. [Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) can help lower the number of conflicts that git cannot resolve automatically.
3. [merge-strategies](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) can help too
4. In a case where there genuinely is a conflict and it's not oblivious what to do, then you will need to resolve them yourself. Many tool provide a 3-way merge to simplify this process.

Comment: In this case there are only a couple main scripts, with probably 80% of changes going to the main "bot.py" file that runs the whole thing - although there *are* ways to split its functionality into different files, which I may do going forward to help prevent issues like this. Thank you for all the suggestions!

Comment: Yes, having a single file changed often by many people will likely lead to many conflicts that will require a human intervention.